# Luminators not working?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, minecraft-industrialcraft

I know people don't think too much of luminators, but I've always been a fan. Playing on IC2 for MC1.7.10 I never had any trouble. I just starting a MC1.10.2 world using IC2 2.6.161 and luminators don't really seem to work. One was definitely on; most seemed to be totally off. Anyone have any luck with this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I see one Generator and one Batbox, and at least 6 luminators. (Are there more outside that screenshot?) You might just have EU supply problems. Do you have an [EU-Reader](http://wiki.industrial-craft.net/index.php?title=EC-Meter) that you can use to tell us how much EU is passing through each luminator's cable?

Comment: There are 12 luminators, but the eu-reader says no current is passing through the line. The total draw (I think) is 49*.2 + 12*.25 = 12.8 EU/t (49 tin wires and 12 luminators). So a regular 32 should be able to do that as far as i understand it

Comment: Which line has no current? Can you check the EU usage in a) the batbox's own UI b) the line out of the batbox, c) the beginning of each parallel branch of cable to the luminators, d) each luminator's final cable segment? The idea is to isolate where in the network the lack/insufficiency of EU begins.

Comment: The eu-reader says 0 EU/t for both in and out at all of the above spots and for the luminators themselves; the batbox gui registers no output (its buffer value is unchanged). As a control, if i hook up a machine to the same wire, it draws power like usual, and the eu-reader can detect the current in the line. There aren't any luminators on now, but earlier when i had the same setup a single one of the 12 was on. Not sure if that's helpful/relevant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow. Problem solved. Apparently right-clicking a luminator turns in on/off. Who knew.

Comment: Hey, if it's non-obvious and solves the problem, it's a good answer! I'm sure others will run into this too, and be helped by this. :)